# Integral of $\int{\frac{\cos^4x + \sin^4x}{\sqrt{1 + \cos 4x}}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

How do we integrate the following?

> $\int{\frac{\cos^4x + \sin^4x}{\sqrt{1 + \cos 4x}}dx}$ given that $\cos 2x \gt 0$

I tried to simplify this, but I cannot seem to proceed further than the below form:

> $\int{\frac{\sec2x}{\sqrt{2}}dx + \sqrt{2}\int{\frac{\sin^2x\cos^2x}{\cos2x}dx}}$
>
> $\implies \frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\log |\sec 2x + \tan 2x| + \sqrt{2}\int{\frac{\sin^2x\cos^2x}{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}dx} + C$

The answer that I'm supposed to get is:

> $\frac{x}{\sqrt2}+C$

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use $$\frac{\sin^4x+\cos^4x}{\sqrt{1+\cos4x}}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^22x}{\sqrt2\cos2x}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos^22x}{\sqrt2\cos2x}=\frac{\cos2x}{2\sqrt2(1-\sin^22x)}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\cos2x=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}\left(\frac{\cos2x}{1+\sin2x}+\frac{\cos2x}{1-\sin2x}\right)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\cos2x.$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I made an error in the question... Let me rectify it.

Comment: There! The $1 + \cos4x$ in the denominator was supposed to be under a root

Comment: I added something. See now.

Comment: Shouldn't the simplification of $\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos^22x}{\sqrt2\cos2x}$ be  $\frac{1 + \cos^22x}{2\sqrt2\cos2x}$? Which would then give $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}\cos2x} + \frac{cos2x}{2\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: Yes, but see also the rest.

Comment: I understood the rest but the thing is when I try to go back from step 4 to step 3, I'm getting a different answer. I.e. I'm getting $\frac{1+cos2x}{2\sqrt2 cos2x}$ instead of $\frac{1+cos^22x}{2\sqrt2 cos2x}$ :/

Comment: It should be $\frac{1+\cos^22x}{2\sqrt2\cos2x}$ because $\sin^22x=1-\cos^22x.$  I can to show another way to get it if you want.

Comment: I have no doubts in that. I'm talking about the step that comes after the above mentioned substitution. What I'm trying to say is, your expansion of $\frac{1+cos^22x}{2\sqrt2cos2x}$ might be wrong...

Comment: $\frac{1+\cos^22x}{2\sqrt2\cos2x}=\frac{\cos2x}{2\sqrt2\cos^22x}+\frac{\cos2x}{2\sqrt2}.$ Do you agree with me?

Comment: OMG, all this time I misread $1-sin^22x$ as $1-2sin^22x$... I'm really sorry for the inconvenience caused. Yes, I totally agree with you :)

Comment: It's OK. Ask your questions.

Comment: Thank you! Until the next question, cheerio!

Answer (score 3):

> $$\int { \frac { \cos ^{ 4 } x+\sin ^{ 4 } x }{ \sqrt { 1+\cos4x }  } dx } =\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } \int { \frac { { \left( \sin ^{ 2 }{ x+\cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  }  \right)  }^{ 2 }-2\sin ^{ 2 }{ x\cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  }  }{ \sqrt { \cos ^{ 2 }{ 2x }  }  } dx } =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } \int { \frac { 1-\frac { \sin ^{ 2 }{ 2x }  }{ 2 }  }{ \cos { 2x }  }  } dx=\frac { 1 }{ 2\sqrt { 2 }  } \int { \frac { 2-\sin ^{ 2 }{ 2x }  }{ \cos { 2x }  }  } dx=\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 2\sqrt { 2 }  } \int { \frac { \cos ^{ 2 }{ 2x } +1 }{ \cos { 2x }  }  } dx=\frac { 1 }{ 2\sqrt { 2 }  } \left[ \int { \cos { 2xdx }  } +\int { \frac { dx }{ \cos { 2x }  }  }  \right] =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 4\sqrt { 2 }  } \int { d\left( \sin { 2x }  \right)  } +\frac { 1 }{ 2\sqrt { 2 }  } \int { \frac { \cos { 2xdx }  }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ 2x }  }  } =\\ =\frac { \sin { 2x }  }{ 4\sqrt { 2 }  } +\frac { 1 }{ 4\sqrt { 2 }  } \int { \frac { d\left( \sin { 2x }  \right)  }{ 1-\sin ^{ 2 }{ 2x }  }  } =\frac { \sin { 2x }  }{ 4\sqrt { 2 }  } +\frac { 1 }{ 8\sqrt { 2 }  } \left[ \int { \frac { d\left( \sin { 2x }  \right)  }{ 1-\sin { 2x }  }  } +\int { \frac { d\left( \sin { 2x }  \right)  }{ 1+\sin { 2x }  }  }  \right] =\\ =\frac { \sin { 2x }  }{ 4\sqrt { 2 }  } +\frac { 1 }{ 8\sqrt { 2 }  } \left[ \int { \frac { d\left( 1+\sin { 2x }  \right)  }{ 1+\sin { 2x }  }  } -\int { \frac { d\left( 1-\sin { 2x }  \right)  }{ 1-\sin { 2x }  }  }  \right] =\\ =\frac { \sin { 2x }  }{ 4\sqrt { 2 }  } +\frac { 1 }{ 8\sqrt { 2 }  } \ln { \left| \frac { 1+\sin { 2x }  }{ 1-\sin { 2x }  }  \right| + } C\\ $$

Comment: Nicely done! (+1)

Comment: This is a pretty good, but how am I supposed to simplify this to the given answer?

Comment: you can simplify $\sin { 2x } =2\sin { x } \cos { x } $ or,you go further as $\ln { \left| \frac { 1+\sin { 2x }  }{ 1-\sin { 2x }  }  \right| = } \ln { \left| \frac { \sin ^{ 2 }{ x } +2\sin { x\cos { x } +\cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  }  }{ \sin ^{ 2 }{ x } -2\sin { x\cos { x } +\cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  }  }  \right| = } \\ =\ln { \left| \frac { { \left( \sin { x } +\cos { x }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ { \left( \sin { x } -\cos { x }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }  \right| = } \ln { \left| \frac { \sin { x+\cos { x }  }  }{ \sin { x } -\cos { x }  }  \right|  } $

Comment: I did that one too, but that's no where close the required answer... but I guess it is something as I couldn't even integrate in earlier :D

Comment: what should the required answer be?

Comment: $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} + C$ :/

Comment: How can it be an answer?) You mean derivative of your answer is the expression under integral, right?

Comment: It's of course false that $\sqrt{2\cos^22x}=\sqrt{2}\cos2x$. On the other hand, in every interval where the function is defined, $\cos2x$ has constant sign, so the argument can be easily rectified.

Answer (score 2):

Using $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x=2\cos^2x-1,$

$$I=\dfrac{\sin^4x+\cos^4x}{\sqrt{1+\cos4x}}=\dfrac{(1-\cos2x)^2+(1+\cos2x)^2}{4\sqrt2|\cos2x|}=\dfrac{1+\cos^22x}{2\sqrt2|\cos2x|}$$

For $\cos2x>0,$

$$2\sqrt2I=\sec2x+\cos2x$$

Now use [Integral of the secant function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_the_secant_function)

Answer (score 2):

I figured out why nobody is getting that answer: the question is wrong, the (correct) question is
$$\int \frac{\cos^4 x-\sin^4 x}{\sqrt{1+\cos4x}} \ \text{d}x$$

Comment: Now, that’s a bummer…

Comment: @Rócherz can u help we with how to write math equations like how u edited?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1857018)

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1857020)

Comment: @user264745 this actually answers the question, though the circumstances here seem pretty unusual but this answer does solve the confusion apparently.

Answer (score 2):

If $\cos 2x > 0$ and the integrand is **wrong** as Rudr Pratap Singh points out, then:
\begin{align}
\frac{\cos^4 x-\sin^4 x}{\sqrt{1+\cos 4x}}
&= \frac{(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)}{\sqrt{2\cos^2 2x}} \\
&= \frac{(1)(\cos 2x)}{\sqrt2|\cos2x|} \\
&= \frac 1 {\sqrt2}.
\end{align}
Hence,
$$\int \frac{\cos^4x-\sin^4x}{\sqrt{1+\cos 4x}} \ \text dx = \frac x {\sqrt2} +c,$$
as desired by O.P.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}\int \frac{\cos ^4 x+\sin ^4 x}{\sqrt{1+\cos 4 x}} d x 
= & \int \frac{\left(\cos ^2 x+\sin ^2 x\right)^2-2 \cos^2 x \sin ^2 x}{\sqrt{2 \cos ^2 2 x}} d x \\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int \frac{1-\frac{1}{2} \sin ^2(2 x)}{\cos (2 x)} d x \\
= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int \frac{1-\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos ^2(2 x)\right)}{\cos (2 x)} d x \\
= & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}\left[\int \sec (2 x) d x+\int \cos (2 x) d x\right] \\
= & \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2}}[\ln |\sec (2 x)+\tan (2 x)|+\sin (2 x)]+C .
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

With the substitution

$$y=\sec x+\tan x \implies x = 2\arctan\frac{y-1}{y+1} = 2\left(\arctan y-\frac\pi4\right)\implies dx = \frac{2\,dy}{y^2+1}$$

and partial fraction decomposition, we can break it up into simpler pieces:

$$\begin{align*}
& \int \frac{\cos^4x + \sin^4x}{\sqrt{1 + \cos(4x)}} \, dx \\
&= \int \frac{\frac{16y^4+\left(y^2-1\right)^4}{\left(y^2+1\right)^4}}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{y^8 - 28y^6 + 70y^4 - 28y^2 + 1}{\left(y^2+1\right)^4}}} \, \frac{2\,dy}{y^2+1} \\
&= \sqrt2 \int \frac{y^8-4y^6+22y^4-4y^2+1}{y^4-6y^2+1} \, \frac{dy}{(y^2+1)^3} \\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2} \int \left(\frac{16}{\left(y^2+1\right)^3} - \frac{16}{\left(y^2+1\right)^2} - \frac2{y^2+1} + \frac{y-1}{y^2-2y-1} - \frac{y+1}{y^2+2y-1}\right) \, dy \\
&= \frac1{16\sqrt2} \left(\frac{4y\left(1-y^2\right)}{\left(1+y^2\right)^2} + \ln \left|y^2-2y-1\right| - \ln \left|y^2+2y-1\right|\right) + C
\end{align*}$$